# Deletion of rows in 2D numpy arrays using np.delete()

Tags: python, numpy-ndarray

I am stuck on how to delete rows in 2D numpy arrays, according to some condition. 
My task is *to delete rows that fall out of some condition*.
The problem is that for smaller scale arrays it works fine but for long data it is not working
Where does it crash?
My code until now, identifies the indexes which are out of the condition,but when I use numpy.delete it does not work.
Data type I am using?
I am using a list of 2D numpy arrays.

```
test = [np.array([[2,2,4],[1,30,50],[1,2,40],[1,20,4],[2,2,4],[10,3,5],[1,2,4],[1,2,4]]),np.array([[1,2,3],[1,3,5],[6,3,1],[9,1,2],[1,2,30],[1,3,50],[6,3,1],[9,1,2]])]

def removalOutliers(lnparrs, col,threshold):
    newArr = []
    for i in lnparrs:        
        cta = i[:,col]                         #SELECT COLUMN
        diff = cta[:-1]-cta[1:]                #DIFFERENCE BTW ELEMENTS
        reference = abs((diff - np.mean(diff)))#GET ABS VALUE
        inds = np.where(reference>threshold)#APPLY THRESHOLD TO ARR
        tmp= np.delete(i,inds,axis=0) #HERE IS THE BIG PROBLEM, IT DOES NOT GET THE 2D ARRAY AND DELETE IT FOR LARGE ARRAYS
        newArr.append(tmp)
    return newArr
NEWARR = removalOutliers(test,2,20)
```

**Fake data Returns(right answer!)**

```
[[ 2  2  4]
 [ 1 20  4]
 [ 2  2  4]
 [10  3  5]
 [ 1  2  4]
 [ 1  2  4]]
[[1 2 3]
 [1 3 5]
 [6 3 1]
 [9 1 2]
 [6 3 1]
 [9 1 2]]
```

**Real Data Returns Before applying the Function plot**
[image: Raw Data Plot]
**Indexes of the items that should be delete it**
[image: indexes]

**Real Data Should plot(after removing the outliers**

[image: Illustration of how it should be]

Comment: are you sure your function is actually selecting these rows for your data? Also did you run it through your debugger?

Comment: I think your code is incomplete, where is `lnparrs` defined?

Comment: Also when selecting rows with numpy you can simply use slicing
Ex: `tmp= i[inds, :]`

Comment: I just edited. The code selects exact the rows I want to delete. Or at least the indexes, I was suppose to delete.

Comment: are you sure you plotted the post-processed array and not the old one?

Comment: Yeah, I did, the problem is the result of inds. Which is giving like [500 400] and for me to apply on the delete method I think I should have another format like [500,400]. I think comma is the problem here.

Comment: Hey guys I followed what @rob_m mentioned and I and it worked. I will post my answer after. Thank you all for your help.